# Sql - Does the sum of some rows is content between A and B?

Tags: sql, sum, rows, cube, rollup

I'm currently trying to find, if the sum of some rows is content between A and B.

For example, I need a surface between 100 m² and 105 m²,
so the request should add all the rows until the sum is content between 100 m² and 105 m², and try all the possible solutions.

**What I Have**

```
 ________________________________
 | id | id_biens    | surface    |
 |____|_____________|____________|
 |  1 | 001         |   80       |
 |  2 | 001         |   50       |
 |  3 | 001         |   30       |
 |  4 | 001         |   55       |
 |____|_____________|____________|
```

**Result I'm Trying to Achieve**

(50 + 55 = 105) **id_biens 001** returns true.

```
 ________________________________
 | id | id_biens    | surface    |
 |____|_____________|____________|
 |  2 | 001         |   50       |
 |  4 | 001         |   55       |
 |____|_____________|____________|
```

thank you for reading my post!

Comment: Do the summed rows need to have the same value for "id_biens"?

Comment: Yes it's need to have the same id_biens, there is around 500 id_biens for 2000 rows ...

Comment: I rewrote my query to join on id_biens, and to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Some data. I added a row, to account for duplicate surface areas.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (id int, id_biens char(3), surface int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
    (1, '001', 80),
    (2, '001', 50),
    (3, '001', 30),
    (4, '001', 55),
    (5, '001', 50);
```

This will work for pairs. It's hard to generalize this to an arbitrary number of rows in SQL. It's essentially a combinatorial problem. You might need to check every possible combination of rows, so in the worst case you'd need to generate and evaluate the set of rows {1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, ... 123, 124...1234} (using id numbers here, for example).

For 1000 rows, taking four at a time gives you about 41 billion combinations. Statistical software might be your best bet for this kind of problem.

I think that, in general, the following query is a better approach. (But remember what I said about statistical software.) It changes your output significantly, but I think the change is for the better. It's much clearer which rows make up the total surface.

```
select distinct b1, 
                id_1, id_2,
                s1, s2,
                (s1 + s2) total_surface
from 
  (select t1.id id_1, t1.id_biens b1, t1.surface s1, 
          t2.id id_2, t2.id_biens b2, t2.surface s2
   from Table1 t1
   inner join Table1 t2
      on t1.id_biens = t2.id_biens
     and t1.id <> t2.id
   where t1.id < t2.id
  ) required_alias
where s1 + s2 between 100 and 105
order by b1, id_1, id_2;

b1   id_1  id_2  s1  s2  total_surface
--
001  2     4     50  55  105
001  2     5     50  50  100
001  4     5     55  50  105
```

Combinations of three values. Changes you need to make are in comments.

```
select distinct b1, 
                id_1, id_2, id_3,                    -- Add an id,
                 s1,  s2,  s3,                       -- Add a surface
                (s1 + s2 + s3) total_surface         -- Add surface to the total.
from 
  (select t1.id id_1, t1.id_biens b1, t1.surface s1, 
          t2.id id_2, t2.id_biens b2, t2.surface s2,
          t3.id id_3, t3.id_biens b3, t3.surface s3  -- Third of three sets of columns.
   from Table1 t1
   inner join Table1 t2
      on t1.id_biens = t2.id_biens
     and t1.id <> t2.id
   inner join Table1 t3                              -- Additional join.
      on t1.id_biens = t3.id_biens
     and t1.id <> t3.id
   where t1.id < t2.id
     and t2.id < t3.id                               -- Additional restriction
  ) required_alias
where s1 + s2 + s3 between 100 and 105               -- Correct math here, too.
```

Comment: It's works perfectly well, except that it's doing the sum of 2 "Surface" but it should try as well to do the sum of 4 , 5 "surface" it has to try all combinations. Sometimes for the same id_biens I've got 15 "surface". I know it's gonna take time to try all combinations, but it's need to be done. Thank you very much

Comment: @TheBigJohn: Well, my point is that it seems to take a different SQL query to evaluate each number of combinations. *It's hard to generalize this to an arbitrary number of rows in SQL.* I think you're better off storing data in a SQL database, and using application code to do either an exhaustive enumeration of the sums, or to do dynamic programming.

Comment: Ok Mike, I would like to take a different SQL to evaluate each number combinations, but I'am new in SQL and I don't know how to generate all the sums for all the combination in the table, after i know how to select the good rows. Thanks a lot